# return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

Tags: c

This should be a simple program as I am new to programming but I can't get through this error, any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Please provide a number\n");
    scanf(" %d", num);

    printf("The given num is %s", (num % 2 == 0) ? ("even") : ("odd"));

    return 0;
}
```

I am using *CodeBlocks*. The program runs fine until `scanf` as it prompts to enter a number. But, after I enter the number it gives error **"untitled5.exe"** has stopped working and when I look into the built message it says:

> return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

Comment: write the return type of main: start with `int main()`

Comment: Use `int main(void)`. Also, you might want to double check your `scanf` there

Comment: Read some [C reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website. Be sure to read the documentation  of every function you use, e.g. of [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: The warning you see is because you do not specify the return type of main, The crash is because you are passing incorrect argument to scanf. Look at some samples using scanf.

Comment: Please notice that [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is *not* a compiler (just an IDE, which can run a compilation command). What really matters is your compiler and compilation flags, i.e. how was your source code compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning/error is because this function `main()` **does not specify its *return value type***. Add `int` before `main()` so first line should be `int main()`.

In addition, your crash is because you don't pass the right arguments to `scanf()`. If you want to have the user input go into `num` you should pass its *address* to `scanf()`, not the *value* of `num` itself. so the call should be: `scanf("%d", &num);`.

The fixed version is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Please provide a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    printf("The given num is %s\n",(num%2==0)?("even"):("odd"));

    return 0;
}
```

You're error/warning should be gone now and you should stop crashing.